# Visual C++ 2010 Express C2099 Error for structures initialized with constants in a macro

Tags: c, macros, compiler-errors, structure, visual-c++-2010-express

Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express, SP1
Project Property: C/C++ Advance Compile As: Compile as C Code (/TC)

Message:

```
error C2099: initializer is not a constant
```

Simple Test Case Showing Error:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *stringP;
    int  lino;
} foo_t;


#define bad {static foo_t foo ={__FILE__,__LINE__};}
#define good {static foo_t foo ={"filename",10};}

int main()
{

    bad;        // error C2099: initializer is not a constant
    good;       // no error

    return 0;
}
```

---

This generates a `C2099` error. This code compiles & links correctly under gcc but not Visual C++ 2010 Express (compile as C Code - i.e. /TC option).

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that can be copied and pasted and compiled to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Not sure if this isn't going to bite you someday: on many present-day computers, `int` is 32 bits; `long` is 64 bits -- you are defining some identifiers with misleading names: `#define Word16 int`; `#define Word32 long int`. If you can think about using C99 fixed-width types.
`

Comment: Thanks - I just did a quick test case and I was sloppy.  This, of course, is not relevant to my bug.

Comment: I can compile the sample code without error using Visual C++ 2010 RTM (except, of course, that the linker doesn't like there being no definition for `probe_`).

Comment: Thanks James - are you saying this is most likely a "feature" in the Express edition?

Comment: Do not use `void main()`!  Except in exceedingly rare instances, you should always define main as either `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles well on my system (MS Visual Studio 2005).

You can preprocess your code to try finding the problem manually:

> cl your_file.c /E > stuff.c

This generates a preprocessed file (you probably have to supply a whole lot more command-line options; you can copy-paste them from the project's Property Pages).

> cl stuff.c

This should reproduce the problem. Then try looking at the code in `stuff.c`; if you don't see the problem immediately, try tweaking it (e.g. replacing complex things with 0) - this should hint on the problem.

(Since your system is much newer than mine, some details may be different, e.g. maybe the compiler on your system is called something other than `cl`, but the idea will probably work)

Comment: When compiled with /E option, the errors go away, however, this is not a solution.  It was a good idea to do some tweaking.  I found what it doesn't like is the __FILE__ and __LINE__ macros.  If I replace these with constants such as "abc" and 0, then the link error goes away.  So the next question is why __FILE__ and __LINE__ are not considered as constants?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Microsoft C compiler does not recognize the `__LINE__` preprocessor macro as a constant (presumably because it changes from line to line?), so you can't use it to initialize a structure member.

Generating the preprocessed .i file doesn't really help because it generates legal code that compiles just fine after `__LINE__` has been replaced with a constant.  Apparently, the C compiler is not trying to compile this same preprocessed output.

You should be able to use

`foo.lino = __LINE__;`

later without any problems.  This seems to be a gripe from the Microsoft C compiler.  Other C compilers I've used don't seem to have any problems with this use of `__LINE__`.

The only workaround I've been able to find is to compile the file as C++ code (/Tp).

Answer (score 0):

`__LINE__` macro is not recognized as constant by MSVC compiler when "Edit & Continue" debug database mode is enabled. If you don't care about "Edit & Continue", you can switch to another database mode and the problem should disappear.